# How to replace elements of an inner array on condition/index basis using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've have seen some answers to similar questions, but I haven't seen one touching multiple conditions and I couldn't adapt any to this need.

Basically, `ar1` should have its labels replaced by the urls.

Here is the function beating me:

```js
let ar1 = [
  ["Client", "Date", "Label1", "Label2"],
  ["A", "11/15/2022", "Label1", "Label2"],
  ["B", "11/15/2022", "Label1", "Label2"],
  ["C", "11/15/2022", "Label1", "Label2"]
];
const label1Col = ar1[0].indexOf('Label1')
const label2Col = ar1[0].indexOf('Label2')

let ar2 = [
  ["Client", "Date", "Label2", "Label1",],
  ["A", "11/15/2022", "www.elonscrewing.com", "www.google.com"],
  ["B", "11/15/2022", "www.elonscrewing.com", "www.google.com"],
  ["C", "11/15/2022", "www.elonscrewing.com", "www.google.com"]
]
const ar2label1Col = ar2[0].indexOf('Label1')
const ar2label2Col = ar2[0].indexOf('Label2')


ar1.forEach(function(val) {
  ar2.forEach(function(link) {
    val[label1Col] = link[ar2label1Col];
    val[label2Col] = link[ar2label2Col];
  })
})
console.log(ar1)
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: What are the multiple conditions? Do you mean there must be a match on both client and date?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @AndrewParks! The url columns may change. That's why I'm getting their indexes. Then, values in ```ar1``` should be replace by urls found in corresponding columns in ```ar2```.

Comment: What do you mean by "the url columns may change?" Also, I assume that it can't be that both arrays have exactly the same number of columns and same number of rows, because otherwise the solution is just to ignore `ar1` and the answer is `ar2`

Comment: You have a typo: `Labe2` in the definition of ar2. Not sure if that is relevant but probably is as you try to find the index of `Label2`

Comment: @AndrewParks ```ar1``` has more columns. I know I should have reflected that in the example.

Comment: Correcting the typo certainly gives www.elonscrewing.com instead of undefined

Comment: Are you saying though that there is a 1:1 correlation between rows in ar1 and rows in ar2? Or could they be out of order, and a match on the client and date columns needs to be performed for every row before copying over the necessary columns? You've also not clarified what you mean by a "condition basis"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really check for spelling mistakes - having "Labe2" in ar2 will make indexOf("Label2") return -1.

And btw. 2nd loop is useless (and will most likely cause bugs when your links are not all the same)

Below the fixed code:

```js
let ar1 = [
  ["Client", "Date", "Label1", "Label2"],
  ["A", "11/15/2022", "Label1", "Label2"],
  ["B", "11/15/2022", "Label1", "Label2"],
  ["C", "11/15/2022", "Label1", "Label2"]
];
const label1Col = ar1[0].indexOf('Label1')
const label2Col = ar1[0].indexOf('Label2')

let ar2 = [
  ["Client", "Date", "Label2", "Label1",],
  ["A", "11/15/2022", "www.elonscrewing.com", "www.google.com"],
  ["B", "11/15/2022", "www.elonscrewing.com", "www.google.com"],
  ["C", "11/15/2022", "www.elonscrewing.com", "www.google.com"]
]
const ar2label1Col = ar2[0].indexOf('Label1')
const ar2label2Col = ar2[0].indexOf('Label2')
console.log(ar2label2Col) //this line is what you should have done in order to debug (this line caught the problem / typo)

ar1.forEach(function(val, index) {
    val[label1Col] = ar2[index][ar2label1Col];
    val[label2Col] = ar2[index][ar2label2Col];
})

console.log(ar1)
```

Comment: This did work! Thanks a lot!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! All is shimmering to my eyes as I've been here for a couple of hours wrestling.

Answer (score 3):

Typo in your ar2. specifically ar2[0][2] is labe2 and not label2 (:

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in `ar2`

["Client", "Date", "Labe2", "Label1",],

missing the `L` in Label2

Answer (score 1):

For unordered arrays (/arrays with different orders) just check with an if condition if Date and Client are equal (and string the conditions with &&s together) - see code below:

but at that point you should really think about, if arrays are still the data type you want to work with. This would be way easier with objects (so if you do similar operations a lot, maybe consider converting your arrays to objects (makes life way easier, and code more readable)

```js
let ar1 = [
  ["Client", "Date", "Label1", "Label2"],
  ["B", "11/15/2022", "Label1", "Label2"],
  ["A", "11/15/2022", "Label1", "Label2"],
  ["C", "11/15/2022", "Label1", "Label2"]
];
const label1Col = ar1[0].indexOf('Label1')
const label2Col = ar1[0].indexOf('Label2')
const dateIdx = ar1[0].indexOf('Date')
const clientIdx = ar1[0].indexOf('Client')

let ar2 = [
  ["Client", "Date", "Label2", "Label1",],
  ["A", "11/15/2022", "www.aaaaaaaaaaa.com", "www.google.com"],
  ["B", "11/15/2022", "www.bbbbbbbbbb.com", "www.google.com"],
  ["C", "11/15/2022", "www.elonscrewing.com", "www.google.com"]
]
const ar2label1Col = ar2[0].indexOf('Label1')
const ar2label2Col = ar2[0].indexOf('Label2')
const ar2ClientIdx = ar2[0].indexOf('Client')
const ar2DateIdx = ar2[0].indexOf('Date')


ar1.forEach(function(val) {
  ar2.forEach(function(link) {
  if (val[clientIdx] === link[ar2ClientIdx] && val[dateIdx] === link[ar2DateIdx]) {
    val[label1Col] = link[ar2label1Col];
    val[label2Col] = link[ar2label2Col];
  }
  })
})
console.log(ar1)
```